# Fastest way to build a list from a sparse dictionary and a list of keys

Tags: python

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm having difficulty.

I've got a list of field names, eg

```
fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

I've got (many) dictionaries that use some of these names:

```
values = {'foo': 1, 'baz': 2}
```

What I want is to convert this dictionary to a list of the values, in the correct place to match the fields list, ie:

```
value_list = [1, None, 2]
```

My best solution so far is:

```
value_list = [values.get(field) for field in fields]
```

but is there a better way using zip or something?

In particular, if I've got a long list of "value dictionaries" (say 10000), and they are pretty sparse (say, fields is 200 long, but each "value dictionary" only has about 10 entries), is there a quicker way?

Comment: What's wrong with your solution, exactly?

Comment: Your solution takes one line and it is a very easy to read list comprehension, what else would you want?

Comment: You could do `list(map(values.get, fields))`, I guess (without needing the `list` if you're working in Python 2), but why?  BTW, `values` isn't a great name for a dictionary -- even as an example -- because the `values` name is already in use referring to the method.

Comment: Clarified - it feels like it ought to be slow for sparse dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In particular, if I've got a long list of "value dictionaries" (say 10000), and they are pretty sparse (say, fields is 200 long, but each "value dictionary" only has about 10 entries), is there a quicker way?

Possibly.

1. Build a dictionary mapping keys to their intended indices:

   ```
   idx = dict((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(fields))
   ```

   This is a preprocessing step that you should only perform once for a whole batch of dictionaries.
2. Now loop over the dictionary keys instead of the fields:

   ```
   lst = [None] * len(fields)
   for k, v in values.iteritems():
       lst[idx[k]] = v
   ```

This should be faster when the number of fields is much larger than the number of keys per `dict`, because it skips hash lookups and can construct the list in one go instead of dynamically during traversal of `fields`. (The latter optimization can also be applied in your current algorithm, though.)

Before applying this in your actual code, be sure to benchmark it, because the actual performance depends on a lot of factors including the speed of the hash function (and thus the actual keys) and the overallocation that `dict` performs.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after.  I'll look into benchmarking before I use this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're going to do with the list when you're done with it, you could consider using a generator instead. That wouldn't take any fewer operations, but it might save you building an unnecessary list.

```
value_iterator = (values.get(field) for field in fields) # Python>=2.7

for value in value_iterator:
    #Do something.
```

This way, no operations are performed until it's time to iterate through the "list" of values.

Answer (score -1):

Use `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections as col
cntr = col.Counter(your_list)
```

Then you can do:

```
counts = cntr.most_common()
```

This gives you a list of tuples, which you can list comprehend-ify.

But as the commenters mention, your solution is pretty nice.

Comment: I don't think this is right. The OP never said the dictionary entries are counters.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? I have a hard time seeing how this is supposed to work.

Comment: Apparently, collections.Counter isn't implemented in every version of Python, so depending on the version that the OP is using, this solution may not work for him. I'm using version 2.6, and there's no sign of it in that version. Not in the documentation on python.org, nor in help().

Comment: What the op wants is for a given list like ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] and a given dict like {'foo': 1, 'baz': 2} to obtain a list of values found in the dict if the value's key is in the given list or None otherwise.

Comment: collections.Counter was introduced in python 2.7.something